# Joint normality of a vector derived from joint normal vectors

Tags: normal-distribution, joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

Suppose that we have two random vectors following joint normal distributions:
$$X=[x_1,x_2]'\sim N(0,\Sigma_X)\quad \textrm{and}\quad Y=[y_1,y_2,y_3]'\sim N(0,\Sigma_Y).$$

In this setup, I am wondering whether the following random vector follows a joint normal distribution:
$$Z=[x_1+y_1,\;x_2+y_2,\;x_2+y_3]'$$

Here is my own proof:
\begin{align}&\textrm{By the joint normallity of X and Y},\\
&\forall a\in\mathbb{R}^2,\;a'X\sim Normal, \\
&\forall a\in\mathbb{R}^3\;a'Y\sim Normal. \\
&\textrm{Here, we will show that}\quad \forall a\in\mathbb{R}^3,\;a'Z \;\; \textrm{follows a normal distribution.} \\
&\textrm{Fix}\;a\in\mathbb{R}^3, \\
&\Rightarrow \;a'Z=a_1(x_1+y_1)+a_2(x_2+y_2)+a_3(x_2+y_3) \\
&\qquad \quad \,=\;[a_1x_1+(a_2+a_3)x_2]+[a_1y_1+a_2y_2+a_3y_3] \\
&\textrm{By the joint normality of X and Y, the first and second terms in the barkets are normal,} \\
&\textrm{Thus,}\;\forall a \in \mathbb{R}^3, a'Z \sim Normal \\
&\therefore) \;Z \;\textrm{follows a joint normal distribution} \qquad \blacksquare \end{align}

Is there any part that is wrong?

Comment: It's excessive, because there's a simple one-line proof: $Z$ is a linear combination of a jointly normal (vector) variable, whence it's Normal, too.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your contribution. I am not sure whether the simple proof is applicable in my question because the third element of $Z$ is not $x_3$, but $x_2$ (i.e. In my humble opinion, $Z$ is not a linear combination of $X$ and $Y$)

Comment: That is incorrect: $Z$ is *explicitly* a linear combination.  Nothing in the definition of linear combination precludes multiple appearances of a term!

Comment: @whuber I see! Thank you for your detailed explanation!